# Is there a way to access a flash object's System.capabilities.localFileReadDisable from javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

I need to be able to detect from the javascript side when users set `LocalFileReadDisable=1` in C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg.  This setting disables local file system read access by the flash object.  Is there a way to get to these capabilities from javascript by interacting with the flash object?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).  You will need to create a function in Flash to accommodate this though, so if you don't have access to the source file of your flash object, you could create a second one as it will report the same capabilities.

Something like this in Flash (AS3):

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.system.Capabilities;

function getLocalFileReadDisable():Boolean {
    return Capabilities.localFileReadDisable;
}

if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("isLocalFileReadDisable", getLocalFileReadDisable);
}
```

Then, in JS, if the flash object has an id of `fl`, you'd do this:

```
document.getElementById("fl").isLocalFileReadDisable();
```